# Bremsstrahlung in body tissue

Tags: radiation, scattering, medical-physics

As far as I know, the intensity of the produced radiation from bremsstrahlung is proportional to:

$$I \propto \frac{Z^2}{m^2},$$
where $Z$ is the atomic number, and $m$ is the mass of the particle.

Now, I understand that when trying to produce x-rays in for example radiation therapy, one accelerates electrons onto a target of high-Z material, and then produces x-rays from that.

But do bremsstrahlung have any contribution inside the body ? The tissue is low-Z, and when you use protons for example, or photons, well, then you produce free electrons inside the body, which then go on to damage the DNA and what not. But are these electrons, produced inside the body, even relevant when talking bremsstrahlung, or would that only be true if I were to treat a patient with electrons alone (Which is usually done with surface tumours).

So basically: Will electrons produced by photons, or ions, inside the body via Coulomb interactions contribute to bremsstrahlung at all, or is it only if I treat a patient with external electrons this is an issue ?

Comment: The power radiated (i.e., intensity integrated over an area) does not depend upon the mass of the particles, just the energy and acceleration.  Though I suppose one could re-express this in terms of impact parameter and mass but then the power would be $\propto \ m^{-4}$ or $\propto \ m^{-6}$, I think...